# Sugar ORM: no such table

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

Вот на этом месте (`book.save()`) вылетает исключение (скрин ниже):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Модель таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Androidmanifest.xml`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин исключения которое вылетает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скриншоты вместо кода – это плохая практика.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />` на `<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="3" />`.

Comment: И `Instant Run` отключите.

Comment: Странно, изменил value = "3" и всё записалось...вообще изначально было value = "1", нашел такой же совет на просторах интернета, изменил на 2, всё равно не помогло...а 3я версия пошла хорошо...от чего это вообще зависит? это версия самой orm?

Comment: Смотрите ответ.

Comment: Замените скриншоты на текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключение `SQLiteException: no such table`, очевидно, говорит о том, что таблицы, над который Вы пытаетесь совершить какие-либо манипуляции, не существует.

Возможно, Вы поменяли схему базы данных, но забыли инкрементировать версию схемы БД в `AndroidManifest.xml`.

В `AndroidManifest.xml` замените:

```
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
```

на:

```
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="3" />
```

`VERSION` – это версия схемы базы данных.

И еще, при работе с `Sugar ORM` лучше отключить Instant Run.

Answer (score 0):

В исключении, обычно, пишется прямая ошибка. У вас это:

```
... no such table: BOOK
```

То есть вы пытаетесь вставить новую строку в таблицу, которая еще не создана в базе данных SQLite.

Comment: Так в том и дело, она ведь должна сама создаваться вместе с объектом...